# Why does a test for this.data.length fail?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a Vue component I have a `data()` function that returns an object of data – standard stuff really:

```
data() {
            return {
                PlaceholderHTML: "",
                ProductID: "",
                CustomInvalidMessage: "",
                Form: {
                    Price: "",
                    Currency: ""
                },
            }
        },
```

When some data (usually a File) is posted to the server using `axios`, a `ProductID` is generated on the server and sent back to Vue. I then set the `ProductID` like

```
this.ProductID = response.data.ProductID;
```

All that works fine. In Vue Developer Tools the `ProductID` value is indeed set to `15005`. If I do a `console.log(ProductID)` then I get back `empty string` on initial state and when `ProductID` is set after the `axios.post()` the console shows `15005`.

So why does the following test never succeed?

```
const formData = new FormData();
if (this.ProductID != null && this.ProductID.length) {
      formData.append("ProductID", this.ProductID); // This never happens
      console.log(`Appended ${this.ProductID}`) // This too never prints anything
}
```

So if I remove the `if(... && this.ProductID.length)` part above, then there is no problem:

```
if (this.ProductID != null) {
   formData.append("ProductID", this.ProductID); // Appended as empty string on initial state and then 15005 after this.ProductID is set
}
```

What is wrong with the `&& this.ProductID.length` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.ProductID` is a number and in js the `Number` constructor does not have `length` method only `String` does so, to fix your problem check it like this:
`this.ProductID.toString().length`

Comment: Omg how is anyone supposed to know this stuff?!